# Could not stop Remote desktop service in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

When trying to stop the Remote desktop service in Windows 10, I get the following error:

> Windows could not stop the Remote Services service on Local Computer.

I could stop the service in Windows 7 and 8. Even if I forcefully kill the service from command prompt, it restarts itself. Are there any other ways I can try to stop the service?

Comment: What problem are you trying to address with stopping the Remote Desktop Service. What steps are you doing that does not work?What happens when you run Services.msc and use it to stop it?

Comment: I need to stop this service prommatically in my application to prevent our end users from using remote desktop. When I manually stop the service in Services.msc, this is the error I get, "Windows could not stop the Remote Desktop Services service on Local Computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion" I get the same error even if I stop "Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector" service first. I am just trying to find out if this is a defect in the OS.

Comment: what .net version are you at?  Are you assuming users are admin? IF so, even if figure out how to stop, they can restart. If they are not admin, normal behavior is for RDP to not work. Usually users must be admin or in remote desktop user group.  Also, killing this service impacts more than just RDP.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of legitimate reasons to not want the service running on your machine - the most important of which is keeping the ports closed to prevent potential hackers.

The likely reason the service is not stoppable here is due to a GPO set on a domain. Many organizations use a default "Always On" RDS rule, to prevent administrators from being locked out.

For anyone arriving here that is having trouble, there are two ways to handle this: If it is a GPO, disable it. If it isn't a GPO, then create a GPO (or if not on a domain, set the following on individual machines) to disable the 'allow' rule for port 3389 (if using the default port) on your client machine's firewall.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Disable the service and reboot the machine.

If Microsoft no longer allows us to stop a service, they usually have a reason for that. Don't try to break your OS.

Comment: A lot of Microsoft reasoning for disabling one function or another doesn't have much in common with the end user best interest.

Comment: so  i have to restart critical server because "remote desktop service" that stuck in "Stopping" due to RDP session crash  can be restart LOL